# Unexpected behavior of Rx.Observable.reduce takeUntil concat

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs5

I am surprised about the behavior of the following code (see https://plnkr.co/edit/OVc26DmXpvXqSOJsQAoh?p=preview):

```
  let empty = Observable.empty();
  let source = Observable.range(1, 5)
    .map(i =>
      Observable.timer(i * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source " + i + ": " + x).take(10))
    .reduce((s1, s2) => s1.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2), empty)
    .mergeAll();

   var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);   
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');   
    });
```

yields

```
Next: source 1: 0
Next: source 1: 1
```

--- a long pause here ---

```
Next: source 5: 0
Next: source 5: 1
Next: source 5: 2
Next: source 5: 3
Next: source 5: 4
Next: source 5: 5
Next: source 5: 6
Next: source 5: 7
Next: source 5: 8
Next: source 5: 9
Completed
```

but I had hoped to see **all** sequences show up inbetween. What went wrong?

## Edit:

Note that using `share()`not always cures it. This code fails:

```
   let originalSequence = Observable.timer(0, 1000).take(10).share();

   let empty = Observable.empty();
     let source = Observable.range(1, 5)
      .map(i =>
      originalSequence.delay(i * 2000).map(x => "source " + i + ": " + x))
    .reduce((s1, s2) => s1.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2), empty)
    .mergeAll();
```

and this code works as I expect and I do not understand why

```
 let empty = Observable.empty();
     let source = Observable.range(1, 5)
      .map(i =>
      Observable.timer(i * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source " + i + ": " + x).take(10).share())
    .reduce((s1, s2) => s1.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2), empty)
    .mergeAll();
```

## Edit 2:

The C# version also has a behavior I would not expect, but at the same time behaves **differently**:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace RxScanProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var originalSequence = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(10).Select(i => (long)i).Publish();

            var empty = Observable.Empty<string>();
            var source = Observable.Range(1, 5)
             .Select(i => originalSequence.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 * i)).Select(x => "source " + i + ": " + x))
             .Aggregate(empty, (s1, s2) => s1.TakeUntil(s2).Concat(s2))
             .SelectMany(x => x);

            source.Subscribe(
                s => Console.WriteLine("Next: " + s),
                ex => Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message),
                () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));

            originalSequence.Connect();

            // Dirty, I know
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
    }
}
```

yields (with some delay)

```
Next: source 1: 0
Next: source 1: 1
Next: source 1: 2
```

## Edit 3

Also [switch()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switch) does not behave as i would expect!

```
   let empty = Observable.empty();
     let source = Observable.range(1, 5)
      .map(i => Observable.timer(i * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source " + i + ": " + x).take(10))
      .switch();
```

yields

```
Next: source 5: 0
Next: source 5: 1
Next: source 5: 2
Next: source 5: 3
Next: source 5: 4
Next: source 5: 5
Next: source 5: 6
Next: source 5: 7
Next: source 5: 8
Next: source 5: 9
```

Same (!) behavior for C#

```
   var originalSequence = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(10).Select(i => (long)i).Publish();

    var empty = Observable.Empty<string>();
    var source = Observable.Range(1, 5)
     .Select(i => originalSequence.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 * i)).Select(x => "source " + i + ": " + x))
     .Switch();
```

Comment: What are you hoping to see?

Comment: I hope to see 2 values from each source, since each of it has another point in time when it starts to emit.

Comment: Found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6fdbdb5-3afb-4b36-90e4-e8aca2c01088/rxjs-fromarray-switch?forum=rx

Comment: switch is not an option: "Note that it will unsubscribe from the previously-emitted Observable when a new Observable is emitted from the source Observable, not when the new Observable emits an item. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at what your code does.

```
  let source = Observable.range(1, 5)
    .map(i =>
      Observable.timer(i * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source " + i + ": " + x).take(10))
    .reduce((s1, s2) => s1.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2), empty)
    .mergeAll();
```

First map will transform `{1,2,3,4,5}` into

```
s1 = Observable.timer(1 * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source 1: " + x).take(10));
s2 = Observable.timer(2 * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source 2: " + x).take(10));
s3 = Observable.timer(3 * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source 3: " + x).take(10));
s4 = Observable.timer(4 * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source 4: " + x).take(10));
s5 = Observable.timer(5 * 2000, 1000).map(x => "source 5: " + x).take(10));
```

next, `reduce` will glue them together like this:

```
s1.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2)
   .takeUntil(s3).concat(s3)
   .takeUntil(s4).concat(s4)
   .takeUntil(s5).concat(s5)
```

now lets write a small marble to show what all these streams will yield:

```
s1               --0123456789
s2               ----0123456789
s3               ------0123456789
s4               --------0123456789
s5               ----------0123456789
s1.takeUntil(s2) --01|
  .concat(s2)    --01----0123456789
  takeUntil(s3)  --01--|
  .concat(s3)    --01--------0123456789
  takeUntil(s4)  --01----|
  .concat(s4)    --01------------0123456789
  takeUntil(s5)  --01------|
  .concat(s5)    --01----------------0123456789
```

Now, if you use `share()`, you effectively publish the source. Publish means you multicast to all subscribers at the same time. This works well if there are 2 subscribers, even if one arrives later than the other, the source will continue mid-stream for the second subscriber. Things change when the first subscriber disconnect before the second one arrive. To preserve resources, `share()` will disconnect the source, and resubscribe to it later. Given you started with cold observables, this means they will start again at the beginning, with the long wait.

Since you use `.takeUntil(s2).concat(s2)`, you will actually unsubscribe from `s2` right before you subscribe to `s2` again. After all `concat` wont connect until it receives `completed` from `takeUntil` and `takeUntil` wont emit `completed` until `s2` has yielded. If `s2` yields, takeUntil will instantly unsubscribe from it before forwarding `completed` down stream. This means that s2 will have no subscribers for a split second, and the source will be reset.

What you probably expected was that `s2` would stay connected the entire time, and would keep running in the background. This would work if you had used a hot observable resulting from an active source instead of a cold observable made hot trough `share()`.

I will not go into detail on `switch()` since i believe you already understood the problem there: It will disconnect the previous source when the next one arrives, not when the next one yields.

What you can do, is write your own 'switchOnYield'

```
source.publish(src => src
  .flatMap(inner1 => 
    inner1.takeUntil(src.flatMap(inner2 => inner2.take(1)))
  ))
```

What this does is merge all sources from source together, but add `takeUntil` on them with all latter sources. If any of the later sources yields, the first bunch will be unsubscribed. This works because the first time `src` yields, `.flatMap(inner1` will run. The second time it yields, `src.flatMap(inner2` will merge any item from the later source into the `takeUntil` operator.

[demo here](http://jsbin.com/naveva/3/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Although I marked this as solution it is only so in type-unsafe JavaScript. In rxjs 5.0.0-beta.10 the signature of publish changed such that you cannot flatMap the sequence anymore, since the type must not change: `export function publish<T>(selector?: (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T>): Observable<T> | ConnectableObservable<T> {`. Ouch.

Comment: @MarkusW. Ouch, i'm filling an issue on that.

Comment: @MarkusW. Also, this solution works best if `source`is cold, but the inner observables are hot. It'll also work on cold ones but end up subscribing multiple times to them. If they're not hot you can add `source.map(src => src.share()).publish(src => src` to the first line. But i understood that they are already hot in practice for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you post expected or desired output. It's not clear what you want. For the C# sample, changing source to the following gets you closer (I think, again, I'm not sure):

```
var source = Observable.Range(1, 5)
    .Select(i => originalSequence
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 * i))
        .Select(x => "source " + i + ": " + x)
    )
    //making sure s2 is shared properly, thus concated properly
    .Aggregate(empty, (s1, s2) => s2.Publish( _s2 => s1
        .TakeUntil(_s2)
        .Concat(_s2)
    ))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

That yields the following output:

```
Next: source 1: 0
Next: source 1: 1
Next: source 2: 1
Next: source 3: 1
Next: source 4: 1
Next: source 5: 1
Next: source 5: 2
Next: source 5: 3
Next: source 5: 4
Next: source 5: 5
Next: source 5: 6
Next: source 5: 7
Next: source 5: 8
Next: source 5: 9
Completed
```

This makes sense to me. If you can post desired output, I'll help you get there.

Comment: IIUC this man that I have to call `source.connect()` before usage, right?

Comment: @MarkusW. No, there is a difference between `.Publish(Selector) : IObservable` and `.Publish() : IConnectableObservable`. Also this answer is using Rx.Net syntrax instead of RxJs.